# Run Batch File in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, batch-file

Is it possible to run a batch file as a menu item in studio 2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, go to **Tools | External Tools** in the menus and add your batch file as the Command. You can also pass in any arguments that you want such as the build target, project directories, etc.

Once you do this, your batch file will appear as one of the items on your tools menu. If you want, you can then add a toolbar button for it by going **Tools | Customize | Tools** and dragging the *External Command #* that matches your tool to the toolbar. You will then want to change it to an icon and select an image for it.

The tools are numbered 1 based in the order they appear in the menu.

Comment: How can you find out the number?

Comment: Sorry, missed this. They are numbered 1 based in the order they appear in the menu.

Comment: Another way of figuring out the number: While customizing the menus/toolbars you can open the Tools menu. When in that mode it will replace the name of the tools with their number in the menu. I think you can also drag directly from there onto the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

### Run batch files in VS Solution Explorer directly

This is much better than having external tool since you can execute a batch file simply by double clicking on it in solution explorer just as if you were opening a code file. I've written [a blog post about it](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/11/running-batch-files-bat-from-within.html) that will help you lots to configure it and of course use it.

### A sidenote

You've asked this question 2 years ago, but I see that nobody mentioned this technique so I'm providing this answer for any future reference. I hope it gets upvoted, so it will be near the top for readers to see.

Comment: Great solution. The one downside is that if we set "execute" action as the default, then it would be a pain to open bat-file for editing. I would prefer if VS allows to add in context menu one command: "execute", or "edit". I bet it can be done via simple plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Tools"/"External Tools..." menu item and add your bat-file to "Tools" menu

Answer (score 0):

As A refinement to the given answer:

Say your project/solution have several BAT that are project specific - you wouldn't want to run one from another project - that's what could happen with the above answer - because you have hard wired the path to the bat.

Just set up one external tool nameed "Run BAT", sets its Command to $(ItemPath), and set the initial directory to $(ItemDirectory), The dialog will whinge that  this is not a real executable - but ignore that.

Tie the tool to a button if you want.

Now to run the BAT of choice from the project or solution - just open the .bat for editing and select the "Run BAT" external tool.

you could also set the "use output" option as well and the bats output will be in the output window.